# Are there any objections from using ASP.NET Application_Start for warm-up?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, warm-up

Does anybody known any objections from using ASP.NET method Application_Start for application warm-up?

Especially, for web-services, where is usually required to preload files, caches algorithms and etc.

Exist:

- Service Auto Start Providers, serviceAutoStartProvider, https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series , where we need:

  - Register new `serviceAutoStartProvider`, with concrete **assembly name**.
  - Assign `serviceAutoStartProvider` to IIS App.
  - Configure IIS App as AlwaysRunning.
- IIS 8.0 Application Initialization , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

  - Assign `initializationPage` to IIS App.
  - Configure IIS App as AlwaysRunning.

But, both methods require changes in IIS configuration for each application, what is uncomfortable in case with many-many applications and has additional risks on releases.

In accordance with [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx):

> ASP.NET calls them (Application_Start and Application_End) once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.

Therefore, Application_Start seems like a great place for warm-up code, for example:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(WarmUpBackend);
}
```

It requires only configure IIS App as **AlwaysRunning**. In `WarmUpBackend` we can preload everything what we need for web-services.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a [Service autostart provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/serviceautostartproviders/).

[Scott Guthrie](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) has a blog post about this.

Comment: Joe, thanks, but why this approach is better than addresses this scenario, than Application_Start? My questions is related for warm-up some web-services, without requests to web-pages. Because for web-services usually the most expensive: queries to DB, files preloading into cache and etc.